# Создание копии БД Oracle

Tags: oracle, база-данных

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть рабочая база oracle 10.2.0.4 на RHEL 5.Потребовался еще один тестовый сервер. Пришлось поставить Windows Server 2008 из-за специфического софта который там еще будет жить.Подскажите, как проще всего и малой кровью создать полноценную копию базы на новом сервере?

P.S. с ораклом в плане администрирования раньше не работал) Сильно не пинайте

Answer (score 1):

Это же 10 версия, там же есть , imp**dp** и exp**dp**, они пошустрее будут, чем cтарые добрые утилиты экспорта-импорта..

А вообще, я бы и на тестовом сервере поднял RHEL5, это было бы более правильно на мой взгляд. А то потом отлавливать глюки "на тесте работает без проблем, а на рабочем не работает совсем...". Оно вам надо ???

Answer (score 0):

Если просто перенести схемы (пользователей в БД Оракл) то это делается через утилиты IMP и EXP.

А вот для полноценной копии БД, надо все таки знать что там задействовано и что используется в базе.

Т.е. дайте побольше инфы

Нашел очень похожую [тему](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=942605&hl=%ea%ee%ef%e8%ff%20%e1%e4), советую изучить ее.